# Can malloc be used for dma?

Tags: malloc, dma

I have some sample code which uses 2 test application:

1. test application in kernel , which allocates buffer using kmalloc
   (GFP_KERNEL)
2. test application in userspace which allocates buffer using malloc
   In this case the kernel driver use copy_from_user before dma transfer.

In both cases the buffers are DMA through PCI.
I don't understand how is it that the buffers are allocated with
malloc/kmalloc for DMA.

Does copy_from_user of area which was allocated using malloc, will result in contiguous memory for dma ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to use `GFP_DMA`. Have you seen [this kmalloc() reference](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch11lev1sec4)?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with that. That's why I don't understand how malloc & copy_from_user  can handle the dma...

Comment: The only DMA memory is that allocated by the kernel with kmalloc(). Kmalloc returns contiguous memory. The point of copy_from_user is to move data into the DMA buffer allocated by kmalloc so the device can use it.

Comment: Hi, the copy_from_user is done on buffer allocated with malloc (not kmalloc) , that's why I'm not sure